# Using Content Types programmatically

Tags: content-type

How can I use a content type programmatically?

example: I have a content type called "Doc Template1" and I have added it as a content type in my document library. And when I click New Document > Doc Template1; Microsoft Word opens up.

Now, how will I do this programmatically?

I have now retrieve my content types using

```
foreach (SPContentType cType in contentTypeCollection)
```

`{`
       `lstBox.Items.Add(cType.Name);`
`}`

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need only change field value as in follow code.

```
item[SPBuiltInFieldId.ContentType] = "Content Type ID";
item.Update();
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to get the content types of a specific document library is to access these via SPList.ContentTypes which returns a collection of the associated content types to that specific list or library. You can use it like so:

```
using (var site = new SPSite("http://somesharepointsite.com"))
{
   var web = site.RootWeb;
   var list = web.Lists["Some Library"];
   var contentTypeCollection = list.ContentTypes;
   // place your code here...
}
```

Instantiating a new site collection (with the SPSite) contructor is quite time and memory consuming. So if your situation allows it you should rahter use the SPContext.Current.Site or SPContext.Current.Web properties.

Answer (score 0):

it's not so difficult.

```
     SPList docLib; //found your document liberary;

     docLib.ContentTypes.Add(web.ContentTypes.OfType<SPContentType>().Where(c => c.Name.Equals("Doc Template1", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).FirstOrDefault());
     docLib.Update();
```

Comment: I am currently trying your code. but where can I get `.OfType` ?

Comment: .OfType is part of Linq extension methods. the namespace is: **System.Linq**